# Google signin is not working properly on ComponentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, redux, google-signin, react-lifecycle

```
  componentDidMount() {
    window.gapi.load("client:auth2", () => {
      window.gapi.client
        .init({
          clientId:
            process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID,
          scope: "email"
        })
        .then(() => {
          this.auth = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
          this.onAuthChange(this.auth.isSignedIn.get());
          this.auth.isSignedIn.listen(this.onAuthChange);
        });
    });
  }

  // this function will called when auth status changes, according to gapi
  onAuthChange = isSignedIn => {
    if (isSignedIn) {
      this.props.signIn();
    } else {
      this.props.signOut();
    }
  };
```

when page loads for the first time, depending upon the current auth state of gapi, I changed state through the redux store. but it didn't change the state. It always refers to the initial state, which I hardcoded to null.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your onAuthChange if the 'isSignedIn' value is true after the network call (using a console.log(isSignedIn). It looks like you may be retrieving the value too soon after you are setting the the state in Redux. you may want to use a componentDidUpdate here.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    window.gapi.load("client:auth2", () => {
      window.gapi.client
        .init({
          clientId:
            process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID,
          scope: "email"
        })
        .then(() => {
          this.auth = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        });
    });
  }

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  //you should be importing the isSignedIn into props then you will be able
  //to use componentDidUpdate, it will not work otherwise
  if (prevProps.isSignedIn !== this.props.isSignedIn) {
    this.onAuthChange(this.props.isSignedIn);
  }
}


  // this function will called when auth status changes, according to gapi
  onAuthChange = isSignedIn => {
    if (isSignedIn) {
      this.props.signIn();
    } else {
      this.props.signOut();
    }
  };
```